# Is AES_256 stronger than blowfish

Tags: mysql, encryption

I'm considering using mysql's built-in `aes_encrypt`. I normally use blowfish, but mysql doesn't seem to support it natively. How do the 2 compare together? Is one stronger than the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AES has a higher design strength than Blowfish - in particular it uses 128 bit blocks, in contrast with Blowfish's 64 bit block size.  It's also just much newer - it has the advantage of incorporating several more years of advances in the cryptographic art.

It may interest you to know that the designers behind Blowfish went on to design an improved algorithm called Twofish, which was an entrant (and finalist) in the AES competition.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking at security then these two algorithms ranks more or less the same. There is some implementation differences so unless you want to use an external function just go with the build in AES function. If you are going to do it yourself you might want to use a newer encryption algorithm than Blowfish.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in the best public cryptanalysis for both algorithms:

For AES, there exists a related-key attack on the 192-bit and 256-bit versions, [discovered by Alex Biryukov and Dmitry Khovratovich](http://eprint.iacr.org/2009/317), which exploits AES's key scheduling in `2^99.5` operations. This is faster than brute force, but still somewhat infeasible. 128-bit AES is not affected by this attack.

For Blowfish, four of its rounds are susceptible to a second-order differential attack (Rijmen, 1997). It can also be distinguished (as in, "Hey, this box is using Blowfish") for a class of [weak keys](http://lasecwww.epfl.ch/php_code/publications/search.php?ref=Vau96a). However, there is no effective cryptanalysis  on the full-round version of Blowfish at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty subjective, but I'd say AES is more widely used than Blowfish and has been proven secure over the years. So, why not?